# A proof validation about compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

We know that in a metric space $(X,d)$ a subset $K$ of $X$ is compact iff every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence that converges to a point of $K$.

I want to prove the '$\Longrightarrow$' part.Here is my attemt:

Suppose that  $\exists x_n$$\in$$K$ such that every subsequence of $x_n$ is not convergent.

Thus for every $x\in$$K$ ,$\exists \epsilon_0$ such that the open ball $B(x,\epsilon_0)$ that contains $x$ has a finite number of terms of $x_n$.

Now the family of subsets $\{B(x,\epsilon_0): x\in$ $K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ thus there exists a finite subcover of $K$ from our assumption.

$\exists x_1,,,,,x_n$ $\in$$K$ such that $K\subset \bigcup\{B(x_i,\epsilon_0):i=1,2,,,n\}$.

And we deduce that $x_n$ is a finite sequence.

This is a contradiction.

Is this proof valid?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The proof is correct, though an instructor might want to see more detail for the assertion that every point has an open nbhd containing only finitely many terms of the sequence.